# How to extract contents of a file between x to y lines

Tags: unix

I have a text file which has millions of lines. I wanted to extract texts between some X to Y lines. How I can achieve this effectively.

Which is the best method to do this.

Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
sed -n x,yp yourfile > newfilename
```

Just replace x and y with the range of lines from which you want to extract contents.

Answer (score 2):

if your file is really huge, I would do: (assume x, y are start and end line numbers)

```
sed -n 'x,yp;yq' file
```

or

```
awk 'NR==x{p=1}NR==y+1{exit}p' file
```

The above commands will stop further processing after reaching line `y`. It may save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

@rahul answer is correct. 
Alternatively, you can use head and tail in combination:

```
tail -n +x input.txt | head -n y > output.txt
```

This time, tail -n +x prints out the entire file starting from line x, and head -n y prints the first y+1 lines of that . It's redirected to output.txt in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use head and tail.

```
head -n Y yourfile | tail -n (Y-X+1)
```

you should replace (Y-X+1) with the number.